# How is a Chi-square distribution a gamma distribution if it only has one parameter?

Tags: gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I know that the [gamma family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) of distributions are a two-parameter family, but [Chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) only has one parameter.

How is a Chi-square distribution a gamma distribution if it only has one parameter?

Comment: A $\chi^2_\nu$ distribution is a Gamma$(\nu/2,1/2)$ distribution: The scale parameter is always equal to $1/2$.

Comment: A standard Normal distribution has *no* parameters.  How could it possibly be a Normal distribution, then?

Comment: @whuber, normal has mean and variance as parameters, so that seemed clear to me that it was a gamma dist'b'n.

Comment: The *standard* normal has no parameters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's start with the p.d.f. of a gamma-distributed random variable $X$, where $\alpha$ is the shape parameter and $\beta$ is the rate parameter (the p.d.f. is a little bit different if $\beta$ is a scale parameter; both parameters are strictly positive):

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{x ^ {\alpha - 1} \beta ^ \alpha e ^ {-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}
$$

Now let $\alpha = \nu / 2$ and $\beta = 1/2$. After making these substitutions in the equation above, we get

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{x ^ {\frac{\nu}{2} - 1} e ^ {-x / 2}}{\Gamma(\nu / 2) 2 ^ {\nu / 2}},
$$

which you can recognize as the p.d.f. of a chi-square-distributed random variable. Since we fixed $\beta$ as a constant (1/2), *we've transformed a 2-parameter random variable into one that depends on only one parameter ($\nu$)*.